# get links of website in java

Tags: java

I would like to see all links in one website. Let's say website is http://www.ub.edu/web/ub/en/.

How can I do that ?

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.ub.edu/web/ub/en/"); 
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection(); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( 
                            new InputStreamReader( 
                            con.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Do you also want to see the links of all subpages? Like a crawler?

Comment: No, this page's links are enough for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for parsing html. It is easy to use. Here all links will be added on list.

```
String url = "http://www.ub.edu/web/ub/en/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

List<String> listOfLinks = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element link : links){
    listOfLinks.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
}

System.out.println(listOfLinks);
```

Also, there are bunch of questions to related this question. So, keep searching.

Comment: I edited your example a little to make it clearer (hope you don't mind). You don't need to handle each exception here. You can let method rethrow it. Let OP decide how to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by adding few lines of code, without introducing a utility library.

```
        URL url = new URL("http://www.ub.edu/web/ub/en/");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));

        Pattern anchorPattern = Pattern.compile(
                "<a[^>]+href\\s*=\\s*([\"'])((?:(?!\\1).)*)\\1",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            Matcher m = anchorPattern.matcher(line);
            while (m.find())
                System.out.println(m.group(2));
            line = br.readLine();
        }
```